# JSON generation issue in EE

Tags: json, developer, enterprise

I have created a apex class which get called from VF page as @RemoteAction. The method generate JSON. The JSON generation work fine in Dev org but when I moved the same code to EE I getting error CPU time Limit. Not able to understand what is their in EE than Dev org which is getting CPU time Limit. Do anyone have any idea why this happens. I have tested my code in 2 different dev org but their is no issue. The issue stand with EE org only.

Comment: Production orgs often have way more data than development orgs and some algorithms can be [exponentially more expensive](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/fixing-a-common-cause-of-system-limitexception-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded/) as the number of records grow. Is more data involved in your EE case?

Comment: No records in both org is same bec we are using real date for testing too.

Comment: I believe I've seen the CPU limit not enforced in developer orgs; does the operation seem equally slow there i.e. more than 10 seconds to complete?